# EF Core wrong Join entity type name

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have three entities as shown here:

```
public class Application
{
    [Key]
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

Join entity

```
public class UserApplication
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating section =>

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
               .HasMany(x => x.Applications)
               .WithMany(x => x.Users)
               .UsingEntity(ua => ua.ToTable("UserApplication"));

modelBuilder.Entity<UserApplication>()
                .HasKey(a=> new { a.ApplicationId, a.UserId});
```

Running the code is causing an error

> invalid object name => ApplicationUser.

Note - while `OnModelCreating` only entity with wrong name is there. DB Has table with name UserApplication

[image]

Comment: carefully read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many your config is wrong

Comment: the error isn't coming from the code you included in the question. Will you double click on the error to see where it is coming from? take a screenshot and include here

Comment: @someone i refered below url for configuration. https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/ef-core-many-to-many-relationship/#:~:text=Many%20to%20Many%20Relationship%20Using%20Fluent%20API%20In,one%20to%20many%20relationship%20with%20the%20joining%20entity.

Comment: @jerdine-sabio  there must be some convention for join entity name

Comment: @Nil there is, but you explicitly specified `UserApplication`. What is your table named? The convention would be `UserApplications`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My Table name is UserApplications. since it is creating entity with wrong name i specified name explicitly. after that entity with correct name is getting created but entity with wrong name is still there which is giving said error.

Comment: . If the table is called `UserApplications` you should use `ua.ToTable("UserApplications")`. The code specified the wrong name

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Table name is - UserApplication, add below code is there in onmodelcreating => modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
               .HasMany(x => x.Applications)
               .WithMany(x => x.Users)
               .UsingEntity(ua => ua.ToTable("UserApplication"));

Comment: In the previous comment you said `My Table name is UserApplications.`. Does the table actually exist? Are you connecting to the correct database? The error comes from SQL Server, not EF Core, and says the table `UserApplication` doesn't exist. This has nothing to do with conventions. The hard-coded table name doesn't exist in the database used by the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using mixture of explicit and implicit join entity. I'm afraid EF Core assumes 2 separate many-to-many relationships with 2 separate tables. Note that by convention the implicit join entity name is `{Name1}{Name2}` with names being in ascending order, which in your case is `ApplicationUser`.

What you need is to use the the generic overload of `UsingEntity` fluent API and pass the explicit join entity type as generic type argument. Also configure the join entity there instead of separately. e.g.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Applications)
    .WithMany(x => x.Users)
    .UsingEntity<UserApplication>(
        //             ^^^
        ua => ua.HasOne(e => e.Application).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ApplicationId),
        ua => ua.HasOne(e => e.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId),
        ua =>
        {
            ua.ToTable("UserApplication");
            ua.HasKey(a => new { a.ApplicationId, a.UserId });
        });
```